# SQL Performance on selecting first/last row for each user on bigger data table

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have read through quite a few posts with greatest-n-per-group but still don't seem to find a good solution in terms of performance. I'm running 10.1.43-MariaDB.

I'm trying to get the change in data values in given time frame and so I need to get the earliest and latest row from this period. The largest number of rows in a time frame that needs to be calculated right now is around 700k and it's only going to be growing. For now I have just resulted into doing two queries, one for the latest and one for the earliest date, but even this has slow performance on currently. The table looks like this:

```
user_id    data          date        
4567          109          28/06/2019 11:04:45        
4252          309          18/06/2019 11:04:45      
4567          77          18/02/2019 11:04:45        
7893          1123          22/06/2019 11:04:45         
4252          303          11/06/2019 11:04:45        
4252          317          19/06/2019 11:04:45
```

The date and user_id columns are indexed. Without ordering the rows aren't in any particular order in the database if that makes a difference.

The furthest I have gotten with this issue is query like this for year period currently (700k datapoints):

```
    SELECT user_id, 
    MIN(date) as date, data
    FROM datapoint_table 
    WHERE date >= '2019-01-14'
    GROUP BY user_id
```

This gives me the right date and user_id in around very fast in around ~0.05s. But like the common issue with the greatest-n-per-group is, the rest of the row (data in this case) is not from the same row with date. I have read about other similar questions and tried with subquery like this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.date, a.data
FROM datapoint_table a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT datapoint_table.user_id, 
    MIN(date) as date, data
    FROM datapoint_table 
    WHERE date >= '2019-01-01'
    GROUP BY user_id
) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.date = b.date
```

This query takes around 15s to complete and gets the correct data value. The 15s tho is just way too long and I must be doing something wrong when the first query is so fast. I also tried doing (MAX)-(MIN) for the data with group by for user_id but it also had slow performance.

What would be more efficient way of getting the same data value as the date or even the difference in latest and earliest data for each user?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have composite index on both user_id and date columns, only individual indexes. The accepted answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a fairly recent version of either MariaDB or MySQL, then `ROW_NUMBER` would probably be the most efficient way to find the earliest record for each user:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM datapoint_table
    WHERE date > '2019-01-14'
)

SELECT user_id, data, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

To the above you could also consider adding the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON datapoint_table (user_id, date);
```

You could also try the following variant index with the columns reversed:

```
CREATE INDEX ON datapoint_table (date, user_id);
```

It is not clear which version of the index would perform the best, which would depend on your data and the execution plan.  Ideally one of the above two indices would help the database execute `ROW_NUMBER`, along with the `WHERE` clause.

If your database version does not support `ROW_NUMBER`, then you may continue with your current approach:

```
SELECT d1.user_id, d1.data, d1.date
FROM datapoint_table d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
    FROM datapoint_table
    WHERE date > '2019-01-14'
    GROUP BY user_id
) d2
    ON d1.user_id = d2.user AND d1.date = d2.min_date
WHERE
    d1.date > '2019-01-14';
```

Again, the indices suggested should at least speed up the execution of the `GROUP BY` subquery.

Comment: I read that window functions are supported only on MariaDB 10.2 or higher and Im running 10.1.43. I will upgrade my version and try row_number() if it helps.

Comment: @Jack477 I also gave you an option for earlier versions.  In any case, the biggest performance-booster here might be to index your table.

Comment: I tried the alternative and it was roughly the same 14-15s. Date and user_id columns are indexed if that is what you mean.

Comment: You need an index covering _both_ columns at the same time.  Just one or the other might not be effective.

Comment: Thank you for this information I wasn't aware that you could do that, but unfortunately it didn't help for the approach I'm using at the moment.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT` on your query _after_ adding one of the two indices I suggested.  Does MariaDB tell you that it is even using that index?

Comment: I havent used explain a lot so I cant really if it is using it. It returns 3 rows and I think the last one is the importnat one it says select_type derived, table datapoint_table, type index, possible_keys date, key user_id

Comment: Im terribly sorry for the format but this is my first time really posting and I dont know if posting pictures is allowed or typing code into comments. Regardless I REALLY appreciate you taking time to help me.

Comment: This is about as much help as I can offer given what I know.  Maybe someone else can post as well.

Comment: Never mind this actually did the trick the query is now 0.03 seconds! Thank you so much man you have no idea how happy you just made me. I will mark your answer as correct one if that's what people do here. If there is anything else I can do here just lmk!